# Run-tim error '2471' the expression you entered as a query parameter produced this error:'[invoicetopid]'

Tags: ms-access, vba

```
Private Sub Form_Current()
Form_frmInvoiceTop.txtInvoicePrice = DSum("invoiceSubTotalPrice", "tblinvoicesub", "[invoicetopid]=forms!frminvoicetop.invoicetopid")
End Sub
```

What is the reason for this error?

Answer (score 1):

You must concatenate the value:

```
Form_frmInvoiceTop.txtInvoicePrice = DSum("invoiceSubTotalPrice", "tblinvoicesub", "[invoicetopid]=" & Forms!frminvoicetop!invoicetopid & "")
```